# cursor iteration with modification in pymongo

Tags: python, cursor, pymongo

Here is my snippet:

```
mongo_db = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://p2buser:p2bpass@192.168.1.102:27018')['YYPei']
brands = mongo_db.fqBrands.find()
count= brands.count()
i = 0
for brand in brands:
    i += 1
    mongo_db.fqBrands.update({"_id": brand['_id']},{'$set': {'enabled': 1})
print count
print i
```

---

there are **1603** elements in the fqBrands collection,and the count is equals to it.
and **i** should be **1603**
but it results that the value of i was **1687**

so it make me a little bit confuse, how can I make certain what's wrong with it.

Comment: What does `print brands.count(with_limit_and_skip=True)` prints? Also, do you use replica sets?

Comment: Also, what if you remove that `update` statement, do you the same results printed?

Comment: @alecxe I get the same behavior (although I use bulk UpdateOne's and have millions of records). with_limit_and_skip makes no difference. Without the update it doesn't occur. No non-default settings on the database (not sharded/no replica sets, etc). Nearly all (but not all) records are updated if I ignore iterations where `i >= count`. Also tried running validate(true) on db, but no effect). I suspect the cursor is getting modified somehow.  mongodb v2.4.9, pymongo 3.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the reason of different values of 'i'.
But there is a better way to update all documents:

```
mongo_db = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://p2buser:p2bpass@192.168.1.102:27018')['YYPei']
brands = mongo_db.fqBrands.find()

count_before= brands.count()
brands.update({},{'$set': {'enabled': 1}, {multi: true})
count_after= brands.count()

print count_before
print count_after
```